# Notify User to New Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongodb with mongoose and node.js with express.

I'm building a communication platform where users can post suggestions for certain other users to view and respond. If two users are using at once, is there a way for there to be live real time updates of new suggestions. I know I can use websockets for this, but I was wondering what standard practice is without websockets. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I've only been coding for 6 months, so I'm still learning! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

socket.io

it uses websocket when possible. If browser does not support it.long polling is used

But you write the same code once for all situations. it handles them for you